# Unable to play video in opencv3?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

Here is my code. Unable to play a video file in opencv3.3. I am beginner to OpenCV. Please help me.

```
int main(void) {
cv::VideoCapture capVideo;

cv::Mat imgFrame;

capVideo.open("C:\\Users\\sbv\\Documents\\MyVideo.avi");

if (!capVideo.isOpened())  {                                                 
    std::cout << "\nerror reading video file" << std::endl << std::endl;      
    _getch();                   
    return(0);
         }

if (capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) < 1) {
    std::cout << "\nerror: video file must have at least one frame";
    _getch();
    return(0);
}

capVideo.read(imgFrame);

char chCheckForEscKey = 0;

while (capVideo.isOpened() && chCheckForEscKey != 27) {

    cv::imshow("imgFrame", imgFrame);

    if ((capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) + 1) < capVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) 
            {
            capVideo.read(imgFrame);                          
    }
    else 
            {
             std::cout << "end of video\n";
             break;                                              
    }

    chCheckForEscKey = cv::waitKey(1);      
        }

if (chCheckForEscKey != 27) {               
    cv::waitKey(0);                             
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Error is coming as :

> Error reading video file.

Please solve this issue.

Comment: Clearly the error is in this line --
capVideo.open("C:\\Users\\sbv\\Documents\\MyVideo.avi");

Comment: what is the error I couldn't find out. I am new to Opencv. with what I need to replace that line. @I.Newton

Comment: Please make sure that the file  `opencv_ffmpeg330.dll` is present in the current directory or system path.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to copy the opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll file into my project's folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite clear 
capVideo.open("C:\Users\sbv\Documents\MyVideo.avi");

You try open MyVideo.avi in path:

```
C:\\Users\\sbv\\Documents\\MyVideo.avi
```

but the file does not exist at that path.

Quick fix: work in cygwin

```
capVideo.open("C:/Users/sbv/Documents/MyVideo.avi");
```

Or put MyVideo.avi in the same directory as your program.

Comment: No. Same error is coming even after changing as u said @gachiemchiep

Comment: How about change : capVideo.open("C:/Users/sbv/Documents/MyVideo.avi");
 into capVideo.open("MyVideo.avi");   . And copy MyVideo.avi into same directory as your program path

Comment: That's weird, did you try open MyVideo.avi by some video player to check whether it is readable?